# Magento 2 configurable attributes order

Tags: magento2, configurable-product

I have a store where the configurable products have size and color as configurable attributes.
The issue i am having is on the product view page, the size dropdown is set to be the first to appear and dependent on the size, the color is displayed in the dropdown.
How can i switch it the other way round, so that i choose color first and then size?

Comment: As a templating option, you might be able to just override `vendor/magento/module-configurable-product/view/frontend/templates/product/view/type/options/configurable.phtml` to move the color attribute to the top of `$_attributes`, but I'm not really too sure if that will effect the functionality like you're looking for (can't test right now)

Comment: I was wondering, is not the configurable attributes controlled by the position?
I tried changing the positions, but still does not solve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

From the backoffice, on product page, in "Configurations" tab.

You can click on "Edit Configurations".

Click on "Next" to go to "Attribute Values" step.

Then you can choose order attribute position by drag and drop.